# Insert images into advertising frames of a 3D modeled advertising bicycle within a web page

Tags: javascript, html, css, three.js

I need to apply mesh to the advertising frames of an advertising bicycle Modeled in 3D in blender, to know the label of that layer and insert an image according to the 3D structure of the advertising box

now I only have a three.js code to insert images on each side of the cube using an html interface using a cube with three.js, but how would I do it to a 3D object that is not basic? In case someone can clarify this problem for me and solve it correctly, I would appreciate it. I would appreciate it, thank you. (by the way the image is in Spanish) [example of my idea preview to insert images into a 3D model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIU7P.png)